# Change charset for CSV Export file

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, export-to-csv

I'm using magento 1.7.0 in Spanish language. When export the CSV file form sales order.The Spanish character are changed. I have found the reason for that.
During the export to csv the charset is set to **western europe**. So now i need to change that to **UTF-8**.

How to change that.

Comment: If nothing helps, try to override the export function and use `utf8_decode()` on the strings. HTH

Answer (score 5):

Check default charset on your server (PHP, apache/nginx). If there everything looks ok, add `<charset>utf8</charset>` to database section in `app/etc/local.xml`, then default_section should looks like:

```
      <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[root]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[magento]]></dbname>
                <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                <active>1</active>
                <charset>utf8</charset>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
```

Hope it helps! Long time ago this charset tag solved some nasty encoding problems in my Magento installation :)