# No UTF8 encoding in Magento blocks

Tags: magento

I am using some widgets for showing new/bestselling items on my frontpage. This widgets need some blocks with the articles in it.

Recently, I moves my magento folder and database to another server and since then, some unicode signs (`€`, `ä`, `ü`, etc) are not shown correctly anymore. First, I thought this could be a database issue, but the encoding ist the same. Whatever non-ascii sign I type it, gets wrong like `Â â‚¬` or `Ã¤`.

Do you know what the issue for this problem can be and how to solve it? I am confused, because I did not change any files or settings.

Comment: Try force charset in mysql connection http://stackoverflow.com/a/26871596/2761930

Comment: I tried, but it did not solved my problem :(

Answer (score 0):

The "Binary" transfer mode of FTP copies files exactly, byte for byte.

Try this method.

Comment: I copied a zipped version from the old FTP and extracted it on the new

Comment: This is typically caused by uploading files through FTP as ASCII file transfer type. The "ASCII transfer type" will transfer the files as regular text files. The "Binary transfer type" will transfer the data in binary mode which handles the files as binary data instead of text data. Setting your FTP client to Binary will prevent your files from becoming corrupted through ftp transit